# How to stop itterating through a map when value is found

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

What i am wanting to do: When a user creates a post have an iterator iterate through a document to see if the users has too many posts. If user has a null field post is allowed

[image]

The issue i am facing is that when the user creates a post it iterates through the list and posts on every null value, not just one.

To solve this issue I added `break;`. This solved my issue but now for some reason when the `break;` statement is used the iterator will only check to see if the 5th item in the document is null not all of the documents.

Code:

```
    currentDocument.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();

                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {

                        Log.d(TAG, map.entrySet().toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, entry.toString());

                        if (entry.getValue() == null) {

                            Log.d("tag", entry.toString() + " is equal to null");

                            posted....
                            break;
```

To solve this issue i found this [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490499/stop-pause-an-iterator) and they said to add a boolean flag (removed break:)

```
public static boolean criteriaMet=false;

currentDocument.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
        if (document.exists()) {
            Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();

            while (criteriaMet == false) {

            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {

                Log.d(TAG, map.entrySet().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, entry.toString());

                if (entry.getValue() == null) {
                criteriaMet = true;

                    Log.d("tag", entry.toString() + " is equal to null");

                    posted....
```

when I use this method the user goes to post it is posted four times and (skips the first null value the itterator identifies and posts on the remaining 4), if the user attempts to post again nothing, happens I don't think the variable is resetting but not sure

full code with the second method commented out i have a few other documents that i am also creating/writing to they are unrelated:

```
        newPostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            currentDocument.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        if (document.exists()) {
                            Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();

                           //     while (criteriaMet == false) {

                                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {

                                        Log.d(TAG, map.entrySet().toString());
                                        Log.d(TAG, entry.toString());

                                        if (entry.getValue() == null) {
                                            criteriaMet = true;

                                            Log.d("tag", entry.toString() + " is equal to null");

                                            postProgress.setTitle("Posting");
                                            postProgress.setMessage("This Should Only Take A Second");
                                            postProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                                            postProgress.show();

                                            final String desc = newPostDesc.getText().toString();

                                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(desc)) {

                                                final String randomName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

                                                final StorageReference filePath = storageReference.child("post_images").child(randomName + ".jpeg");
                                                filePath.putFile(postImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                                            File newImageFile = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(postImageUri.getPath()));
                                                            try {
                                                                compressedImageFile = new Compressor(NewPost.this)
                                                                        .setMaxHeight(200)
                                                                        .setMaxWidth(200)
                                                                        .setQuality(10)
                                                                        .compressToBitmap(newImageFile);

                                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                                            }

                                                            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                                            compressedImageFile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                                                            byte[] thumbData = baos.toByteArray();

                                                            final UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.child("post_images/thumbs").child(randomName + ".jpeg").putBytes(thumbData);

                                                            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                                                }
                                                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {


                                                                }
                                                            });

                                                            filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                                                    final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                                                                    Log.d("tag", downloadUrl);

                                                                    FirebaseUser current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                                                                    String uid = Objects.requireNonNull(current_user).getUid();

                                                                    final Map<String, Object> postMap = new HashMap<>();
                                                                    // No thumb ?????
                                                                    postMap.put("image_url", downloadUrl);
                                                                    postMap.put("desc", desc);
                                                                    postMap.put("user_id", current_user_id);
                                                                    postMap.put("message_doc", uid + postCategory);
                                                                    postMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());


                                                                    firebaseFirestore.collection(postCategory).add(postMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {

                                                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {


                                                                                firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").add(postMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                                                                    @Override
                                                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<DocumentReference> task) {

                                                                                        FirebaseUser current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                                                                                        String uid = Objects.requireNonNull(current_user).getUid();

                                                                                        final Map<String, String> chatMap = new HashMap<>();
                                                                                        postMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
                                                                                        postMap.put("name", current_user_id);
                                                                                        postMap.put("message", "");

                                                                                        firebaseFirestore.collection("Messages")
                                                                                                .document(uid + postCategory)
                                                                                                .set(chatMap)
                                                                                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                                                                    @Override
                                                                                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                                                                        final String BlogPostID = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getId();

                                                                                                        String document_Id = current_user_id + postCategory;

                                                                                                        final Map<String, String> usermap = new HashMap<>();
                                                                                                        usermap.put("Owner", current_user_id);
                                                                                                        usermap.put("debater", null);

                                                                                                        firebaseFirestore.collection("Messages").document(document_Id)
                                                                                                                .set(usermap)
                                                                                                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                                                                                    @Override
                                                                                                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                                                                                                        //write to active posts document

                                                                                                                        postProgress.dismiss();
                                                                                                                        Intent startIntent = new Intent(NewPost.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                                                                                        startActivity(startIntent);

                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                });
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                });


                                                                                    }
                                                                                });

                                                                            }


                                                                        }
                                                                    });


                                                                }
                                                            });

                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });


                                            }


                                        } else {
                                            Log.w(TAG, "the value is not null");

                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Too many active debates", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        }

                                        break;
                                    }
                              //  } //attached to while crit loop
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });}
```

I have been working on this for a few days and I am stumped if any more info is required let me know.

Comment: Why is the `break` not inside a conditional? Why is the `for` indented more than the line before it? Also, this code hurts my eyes. The goggles! They do nothing!

Comment: You should rewrite this focusing on SOLID design principles then it will become easier to maintain and debug.

Comment: There's an onSuccess listener nested inside the onSuccess listener nested inside the onComplete listener nested inside the onComplete listener nested inside the onSuccess listener nested inside the onComplete listener nested inside the onComplete listener nested inside the onClick listener. And that isn't even the problem.